# PHP in Eclipse, how to run PHP on some server?

Tags: php, eclipse, apache

On Eclipse i installed the `PHP` Development Tools and everything is cool, except i can't configure it to run on my local Apache...

I saw something like placing all my project files in some `htdocs` directory of Apache directory... but its kinda absurd...

I already tried:

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/running_php_web_pages.htm

and

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/php_servers.htm#Adding_servers

Which, as i understood, is linking calls from `localhost/[project-name]` (which directory is placed as `htdocs`) to my original repository `x:/y/[project-name]`, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You might need to setup the workspace for your eclipse. The directory you set as workspace works as the document root directory and you don't need to place everything in htdocs. Hope this helps.